# Line art disappears when camera get close

Tags: lineart

[image]

Line art disappears when camera get close to some shapes in blender 3.0. win11.

When tested on version 2.93 it works fine. The problem only occurs in 3.0.

As you can see in the screenshot, This usually happens with angled shapes -like basic cube shape. When viewed from a distance, it prints just fine.

I checked object line art property 'inherit'. I figured this had no reason other than a bug.

Is this really a bug? Any help would be appreciated.

*I don't speak English well, so I used a translator. Please understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Blender right now, but from the right-side viewport it looks like lines get culled out when they are beyound a certain margin.

There has been [quite a lot of GP changes on v3.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Grease_Pencil), I think particularly about the [camera overscan](https://developer.blender.org/rB8e9d06f5). So most likely it's just a difference in default parameters or new features that need you to change some settings somewhere.

So I'd suggest you to go to the `Properties Editor` > `Render` tab > `Film` panel and see how it goes by making the [overscan](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/render_settings/film.html#film) larger.

Also, AFAIK when you make freestyle lines from meshes, the lines vertices are made from the mesh itself. Here you have a cube with no vertices in-between its edges, so when you zoom on it, unlike the sphere it doesn't have a lot of vertices from which to draw lines, and the cube's vertices get quickly out of the camera's overscan.
Maybe a good solution would be to simply add more subdivisions to you mesh (I.E. adding a [Subdivide modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/subdivide.html) with its subdivision type set `Simple`).

Probably both solutions combined is better, actually. But do some tests and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed comment. 
I increased overscan and nothing happened, but subdivision solved this problem.